# drawPolyline() does not paint correctly

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, polyline

I implement a program that creates polyline dynamically using mouse clicks. Each mouse click adds new Point in an ArrayList and draw it all. if I click same Point it returns same value and add it to list but it draws new line to 0, 0. I wonder what is reason.

```
private ArrayList<Point> liste;

public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);

    int xn[] = new int[liste.size()];
    int yn[] = new int[liste.size()];
    for(Point pot : liste){
        int ab = liste.indexOf(pot);
        xn[ab] = pot.x;
        yn[ab] = pot.y;

    }
    page.setColor (Color.red);

    page.drawPolyline(xn, yn, xn.length);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    liste.add(arg0.getPoint());
    repaint();
    System.out.println(arg0.getPoint());

}
```

http://i.hizliresim.com/r9YgkM.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you use `indexOf` to find the index in the array.

Because of the way [`Point` implements `equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), if you have clicked exactly the same point, `indexOf` will return the index of the first matching `Point`, not the second (or subsequent) occurrence. As such, the array elements corresponding to the second (or subsequent) occurrences will remain at their default value, zero.

Instead, just declare `ab` outside the loop, and increment inside the loop:

```
int ab = 0;
for(Point pot : liste){
    xn[ab] = pot.x;
    yn[ab] = pot.y;
    ++ab;
}
```